# html elements in the request parameter is not retrieved in the server side

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio

My project have following structure.

The pages is in the html file. and server request is processed on `Page_load` in the other `aspx page`.

I created a sample application to show the error.
Here is the HTML file `HTMLPage1.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var params = 'pak=' + encodeURIComponent('</br>');
        debugger;
        var url = 'http://localhost:49735/WebForm1.aspx?' + params;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            url: url,
            success: function (data) {
                alert('Hi');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Here is the PageLoad function in `WebForm1.aspx.cs`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var authorize = Request["pak"];
  int i = 0;
}
```

But `Request["pak"]` is not accessible. I should need to pass pak as `</br>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call web by `POST`

You should set the `data` field

like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //var params = 'pak=' + encodeURIComponent('</br>');
    debugger;
    var url = 'http://localhost:49735/WebForm1.aspx';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        data:{
            pak : encodeURIComponent('</br>')
        },
        url: url,
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Hi');
        }
    });
});
```

`encodeURIComponent('</br>')` will encodeURL like `"%3C%2Fbr%3E"`

You can try to use `HttpUtility.UrlDecode()` to Decode

```
var authorize =  HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request["pak"].toString());
```

You will get `</br>`

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. to decode. i used HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.Form["pak"]).

Comment: It's my pleasure :).